# How to determine if the current character is a letter

Tags: elisp, characters

How I can determine if the current character is a letter (an alphabetic character) (i.e., belongs to the syntax class `[:alpha:]` in regexp notions).
I would like to write a simple function like below:

```
(defun test-letter () (interactive)
(if char-after-is-a-letter
    (message "This is a letter")
    (message "This is not a letter")
    )
)
```

**Update**
Unfortunately my assumption about the equivalence of the class of the letters and the syntax class `[:alpha:]` seems to be false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Use Unicode char properties

This should definitely work:

```
(memq (get-char-code-property (char-after) 'general-category)
      '(Ll Lu Lo Lt Lm Mn Mc Me Nl))
```

As a bonus it should also be faster than `looking-at`.

---

[Emacs stores](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Properties.html) all character properties specified by the Unicode standard. They are accessible with `get-char-code-property`. Specifically, the `general-category` property specifies which characters are letters (`Ll` are lowercase, `Lu` are uppercase, and don't ask me what the others are).

Comment: Many thanks, this solves the problem with `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰` but there are some true-negatives, e.g. Arabic or Hebrew Alef: `א`, `ا`.

Comment: @Name Fixed. Try it again.

Comment: Thank you again. I checked it with various Alphabets and it works. The only exception I found is with some Asian alphabet such as Chinese http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals or Japanese http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals. For example `五` is considered as the number `5` in Japanese. Your code considers this a letter. Maybe it is a letter (like in roman number `v`). Maybe somebody who is familiar with Japanese can verify this.

Comment: `五` is like the English word `five`, so it is a letter. When writing the number 5 instead of the word five, they use `5` just like English.

Comment: Note that you can check the meaning of those char code properties with the function `char-code-property-description`. The ones starting with `M` are marks (nonspacing, spacing combining and enclosing), `Nl` is "Number, letter".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:General_Category_(Unicode) also has a readable table with descriptions of the categories.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** This answer should be perfectly valid in 25.5 (where [the bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19878) had been fixed). For older versions, use the [other option](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8282/50).

---

This should tell you if current char is a letter, and should work in any language.

```
 (looking-at-p "[[:alpha:]]")
```

Comment: Many thanks, I am just curious about the difference between `looking-at-p` used in your solution and `looking-at` in the other answer.

Comment: The two functions are equivalent, except that `looking-at-p` doesn't set match data.

Comment: @Name looking-at-p is closer to a pure predicate, because it doesn't set the match data. If you previously performed something like a search-forward, `match-string` (and its many siblings) will return the result of the search. Meanwhile, with the non predicate version, match-string will return the result of the looking-at match.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can get away with this:

```
(defun test-letter ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((char (char-after)))
    (if (and (eq (char-syntax char) ?w)
             (or (> char ?9)
                 (< char ?1)))
        (message "This is a letter")
      (message "This is not a letter"))))
```

### Update

This is a less efficient, but closer to what you want:

```
(defun test-letter ()
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at "[a-z-A-Z]")
      (message "This is a letter")
    (message "This is not a letter")))
```

Comment: Thanks, a possible problem: This function considers the digits (123... ) as a letter.

Comment: Easily fixable.

Comment: Many thanks again. Another false positive: This considers `۹` (i.e., the Indian digit 9) or `٪` as a letter.

Comment: Your first solution was fine with Greek letters (such as `ζ` or `α`), but the update is not.

Comment: But combining both is a closer solution.

Comment: Unfortunately `[:alpha:]` matches `۹` as a letter.

Comment: `string-match`/`make-string`?  Why not just `looking-at`?

Comment: @Name, wrong matching of Indian digits is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @lunaryorn, you're right; the lame approach resulted from the previous start.

Comment: thankyou for  this... i have been able to implement the holy grail - if the char at point is english translate it to chinese, if it's not it will be chinese so translate to english!

Answer (score 3):

In case you were very concerned about national characters and precise treatment of Unicode character classes, then the only solution I was able to find so far is the Python [`regex` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Both `grep` and `Perl` (to my utter surprise!) didn't do the job properly.

So, the regular expression you are after is this one: `\p{L}`.  This is known as Unicode property shorthand version, the full version is `\p{Letter}` or even `p\{General_Category=Letter}`.  `Letter` is itself a composite class, but I won't go into details, the best reference I could find on the subject is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Python library isn't built-into the language (it is an alternative to the built-in `re` library).  So, you would need to install it, for example:

```
# pip install regex
```

Then, you could use it like so:

```
import regex
>>> regex.match(ur'\p{L}+', u'۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰')
>>> regex.match(ur'\p{L}+', u'абвгд')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 5), match=u'\u0430\u0431\u0432\u0433\u0434'>
>>> regex.match(ur'\p{L}+', u'123')
>>> regex.match(ur'\p{L}+', u'abcd')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 4), match=u'abcd'>
>>>
```

You could also put this script somewhere where you can access it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import regex
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for match in regex.finditer(ur'\p{L}+', sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8')):
        print match.string
```

And call it from Emacs like so (suppose you saved this script in `~/bin`):

```
(defun unicode-character-p ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((current (char-after (point)))
         (result (shell-command-to-string
                  (format "~/bin/is-character.py '%c'" current))))
    (message
     (if (string= result "") "Character %c isn't a letter"
        "Character %c is a letter")
     current)))
```